# Fragment livecycle / LocationProvider listener

Tags: android

I am having a `Fragment` that is supposed to received GPS location data from the `LocationProvider`. I was considering to let my fragment simply implement `LocationListener` interface but here is the thing:

In my `PagerAdapter` that is providing the fragments to my `Activity` I would have something like this:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch(position) {
        case FRAGMENT_ID_FAVORITES:
            return new FavoritesFragment();
        case FRAGMENT_ID_NEARBY:
            // NearbyFragment implements LocationListener
            NearbyFragment nearby = new NearbyFragment();
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 1, nearby);
            return nearby ;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem I am having is that I don't know if it is a good idea to do that especially since I don't know what happens if `PagerAdapter` returns another `NearbyFragment` - I am not even sure if that is possible.

So is it in general a good idea to do that or should I write my own `GPSProvider implements LocationListener` and register that or should I do something completely apart from that? Sorry I am not having a lot experiance with Android Development or anything related.